# Good Openshift + git workflow for wordpress developer

Tags: wordpress, git, openshift

We are small wordpress focused web development company planning to migrate to OpenShift by RedHat.

My goal is to have production environments (apps) in the cloud and most of the development is done in local laptops using OpenShift origin and then deployed as staging apps to private OpenShift installation and when approved back to cloud replacing original app. It would be extra if all team could be able to edit app simultaneously in the dev version of the app (in the cloud).

The problem I noticed is that web development often requires many edits when tweaking CSS and such and commits to OpenShift takes more than 10 seconds.

Hot deploy (https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1057-how-can-i-deploy-my-application-without-having-to-restart-it) speeds up process a bit, but not enough.

Another option is to SCP/SFTP to local OpenShift installation and edit files bypassing git and build process. That causes git to be off sync, but it can be fixed (http://druss.pp.ua/2013/11/synchronize-openshift-application-after-update/)

How ever, process isn't that smooth as i hoped it to be. Any improvement ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to keep my plugins & themes in git.  That allows me to run a copy of my wordpress site locally for development, then add my changes into git, do a git push, and have the production site updated.  This would require a minimal change to your files you have now if you used the OpenShift quickstart.  I can provide details if needed.

Comment: How do you deal with database?

Comment: Manual data migration, do a mysqldump when you need to refresh your dev data.

Comment: i do not understand the how open files handles directories. lets say i want to install a plugin, where do i put it if i want to do it locally and then push it

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your flow, how you keep the file in git and when you push your life data did not removed?